# How to find drupal 6 ubercart Persian translation?

Tags: ubercart, i18n-l10n

Does anyone has drupal 6 ubercart persian translation or Anyone know how can I find it?
Please help me
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the direct link here:

http://ftp.drupal.org/files/translations/6.x/ubercart/ubercart-6.x-2.9.fa.po

In case you're interested (and for future reference) that comes from the [Ubercart translation downloads](http://localize.drupal.org/translate/downloads?project=ubercart) page on Drupal.org.

You're pretty lucky, it was only generated 2 days ago!